# Query for Summing the values based on text mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Basically i have this table . And i need the sum the **crop_stage** values based on **crop_text**

```
----------    ----------    
crop_stage    crop_text    
----------    ----------
12             Preflowering
3              Fertilizing
10             Sowing
10             Sowing
2              Preflowering
15             Fertilizing
```

And i need to update the **crop_stage** values so that i should get

```
----------    ----------    
crop_stage    crop_text    
----------    ----------
14             Preflowering
18             Fertilizing
20             Sowing
```

I have written my select query which isnt working good.

```
"SELECT crop_text, SUM(crop_stage) AS crop_stage FROM table GROUP BY crop_text"
```

**EDIT**

I am doing json_encode with my select query, which is actually giving me this.

```
[["Preflowering",12],["Fertilizing",3],["Sowing",10],["Sowing",10],["Preflowering",2],["Fertilizing",15]
```

Comment: Works fine here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/567dab/2 What result are you getting instead?

Comment: Works fine for me.May be you have to put your table name in place of `table`.Note that `table` will not be your table name

Comment: put propername for table

Comment: whats your table name? ..its cant be `table` for sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word `table` is reserved. Write the query like this:

```
SELECT crop_text, SUM(crop_stage) AS crop_stage FROM `table` GROUP BY crop_text;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'll bet a million dollars that's not his actual table name.

Comment: Challenge accepted! I see your million and raise it to 2M! :)

Comment: I Bet a million that is the only mistake in that query!

Comment: sorry for wasting your time. I had error with the alphabets in 'crop_text' column :( :D

Answer (score 0):

SELECT crop_text, SUM(crop_stage) AS crop_stage FROM table_name GROUP BY crop_text order by crop_stage ASC